# Google App Engine security exception for Opensaml v3 initialise

Tags: java, google-app-engine, opensaml

*The problem can be referred for [JIRA of the Opensaml v3](https://issues.shibboleth.net/jira/browse/OSJ-205)*

The direct problem can be summarised that when I initialise the OpenSaml v3, the exception (`Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.security.SecurityPermission" "org.apache.xml.security.register")`) will be thrown.

*And the problem can be conducted that:*

GAE is running the app under a Java SecurityManager. So this manager doesn't allow the initialize process of OpenSAML v3. **So is there any method to add these permissions for GAE(standard environment)? or disable the SecurityManager?**

*The exception:*

```
org.opensaml.core.config.InitializationException: Problem loading 
configuration resource
at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.AbstractXMLObjectProviderInitializer.init(AbstractXMLObjectProviderInitializer.java:59)
at org.opensaml.core.config.InitializationService.initialize(InitializationService.java:56)
at com.deepnet.dualshield.sso.utils.SamlUtils.convertBase64ToSaml(SamlUtils.java:40)
at com.deepnet.dualshield.sso.saml2.impl.SAML2ServiceImpl.decodeMessage(SAML2ServiceImpl.java:17)
at com.deepnet.dualshield.rest.sso.SsoProvider.samlRequestHandler(SsoProvider.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:130)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:287)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:277)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:182)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
at org.apache.shiro.guice.web.SimpleFilterChain.doFilter(SimpleFilterChain.java:44)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.shiro.guice.web.SimpleFilterChain.doFilter(SimpleFilterChain.java:41)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
at com.deepnet.dualshield.server.filters.SwaggerFilter.doFilter(SwaggerFilter.java:53)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
at com.deepnet.dualshield.server.filters.LanguageFilter.doFilter(LanguageFilter.java:97)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
at com.deepnet.dualshield.server.filters.ApiOriginFilter.doFilter(ApiOriginFilter.java:50)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:119)
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:133)
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:130)
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$Context.call(GuiceFilter.java:203)
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:128)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLConfigurationException: Cannot create instance of org.opensaml.xmlsec.signature.impl.SignatureMarshaller
at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLConfigurator.createClassInstance(XMLConfigurator.java:318)
at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLConfigurator.initializeObjectProviders(XMLConfigurator.java:243)
at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:203)
at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:188)
at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:162)
at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.AbstractXMLObjectProviderInitializer.init(AbstractXMLObjectProviderInitializer.java:52)
... 96 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_(Runtime.java:142)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance(Runtime.java:150)
at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLConfigurator.createClassInstance(XMLConfigurator.java:314)
... 101 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.security.SecurityPermission" "org.apache.xml.security.register")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:445)
at org.apache.xml.security.utils.JavaUtils.checkRegisterPermission(JavaUtils.java:249)
at org.apache.xml.security.utils.ElementProxy.setDefaultPrefix(ElementProxy.java:475)
at org.apache.xml.security.utils.ElementProxy.registerDefaultPrefixes(ElementProxy.java:498)
at org.apache.xml.security.Init$2.run(Init.java:122)
at org.apache.xml.security.Init$2.run(Init.java:117)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.xml.security.Init.dynamicInit(Init.java:117)
at org.apache.xml.security.Init.init(Init.java:94)
at org.opensaml.xmlsec.signature.impl.SignatureMarshaller.<init>(SignatureMarshaller.java:55)
... 108 more
```